# Async Context doesn't stop on cancellation

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets, jetty

In case a user sends a request and suddenly cancels it. I notice that there would be three cases happen on the server side:

1. ReadListener catches `early EOF` since the available data is invalid
2. onError event raised (this is the expected case)
3. Async Context continues running like nothing happened.

both cases 1 and two are good but when it falls into case 3, the context seems to run forever. How can I handle this situation? How to stop it? I have tried closing the input stream as well as calling AsyncContext.complete() but neither could stop it. it would not enter the onComplete event.